# Rapid changes in signal correspond to high frequencies - proof

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum

If I consider a generic aperiodic signal $x(t)$, how can I prove that rapid changes in signal correspond to high frequencies?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Exactly how are you defining "rapid changes"?

Comment: Hi @hotpaw2, rapid change=high amplitude of derivative.

Comment: Here's a rough handwavy explanation: rapid changes in a signal imply periods where its time derivative is large relative to the "steady state" value. Higher-frequency components have larger first derivatives, so they are needed for the signal to change quickly.

Comment: Hi @JasonR can you explain me your last sentence please?

Comment: The amplitude of the first derivative of a sinusoid of frequency $f$ Hz is proportional to $f$. This makes sense; if the period repeats more quickly, it has to change at a faster rate.

Comment: There are two ways to get a higher first derivative from a composition of sinusoidal components: use low frequency sinusoids with significantly larger amplitudes (the magnitude of the first derivative at the zero crossings be larger), or use higher frequency sinusoids (steeper and more zero crossings per unit time).

Comment: Hi @hotpaw2 are you referring to sinusoids also in the case of aperiodic signals because you are considering the exponential in the definition of CTFT $x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{X(f)exp(j2\pi ft)df}$ as $exp(j2\pi ft)=cos(2\pi ft)+jsin(2\pi ft)$?

Answer (score 1):

One might argue that the Dirac delta $\delta(t)$ , is a signal that exhibits maximum change because all frequencies are uniformly increased, not just the high frequencies